# What are the quota limits for Gmail IMAP read commands?

Tags: email, gmail, imap, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I've written a simple TCP client that monitors the number of emails I get.

I'm refreshing the email inbox using the following command (A100 is just an example unique value):

`A100 SELECT INBOX`

Ideally I hope to refresh this every 15 seconds 24/7. However, I find it difficult to understand what rate-limits Gmail has regarding this. Here are some sources I've consulted which don't make it clear how many commands I can send per minute/hour/per day before hitting the quota.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota

https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518?hl=en

What are the quota limits for Gmail IMAP commands? Or are the quotas mainly aimed towards minimizing bandwidth? I've checked the bandwidth usage of this command and it is very minimal.

Other StackOverflow questions regarding IMAP limits seem to inquire specifically about email sending limits, which does not apply in my use case. I fully understand the quota limits Gmail has on sending emails and bandwidth as it is documented very well.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean about "Gmail IMAP commands" is this the API request endpoints you are referring to that is included on the documentation that you have provided or if it the TCP Server connections and this is more inclined on this reference: 

[https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp]

Comment: You should probably look into the IMAP `IDLE` extension. Also, if you have hardcoded the `A100` token, that's a bug; the ID should be unique.

Comment: @Babanana Broken link; you apparently meant https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp

Comment: @tripleee in my code, I have it unique. However for simplicity of the question, have just pasted a sample.

Comment: @Babanana the IMAP communication protocol can be found documented here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501

Comment: @tripleee I know about IDLE. However, I'd like to know any limitations in polling as it is preferable for my use case. IDLE cannot read emails from the same socket. Have to unsubscribe and then re-subscribe. This can cause some edge case bugs in my simple use of IMAP.

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting the link, the community will greatly benefit on it. I would like to highlight some points about this IMAP connection.  Gmail is using one continuous TCP connection which is highlighted on this article [Session Limit](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp#session_length_limits), therefore there is really no limit on it, as long as the handshake is still valid. There is virtually no quota limit but rather a session limit which is in this case "Gmail IMAP sessions are limited to about 24 hours" highlighted on the same document.

Comment: Please let me know if the explanation gives you some clarification about the subject so I can post this as an answer and help the community know that their same questions have answers.

Comment: Just because it is 1 TCP connection does not mean there is no limit as long as you're connected to the IMAP server.

Comment: You are correct @BayanR but this is for polling since there is no documented about the limits it is virtually non existent, I have found old post that directly correlated your questions did you have a chance to read this ?https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49721/what-is-the-maximum-frequency-for-checking-email-in-gmail-and-are-there-alterna

Comment: Yes. It does not answer the question about "how much is too much".

Comment: In this case you can actually post you question here[Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) this way a Googler can address your question.